# How to display QGIS plugin panel "OSM place search"?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

It is possible to hide the panel for the experimental QGIS plug-in 'OSM place search' - but the panel is not listed (to re-display) under the menu item View | Panels. How can it be re-displayed?

Answer (score 2):

There turn out to be two methods (more?) to see the list of available 'panels' in QGIS. 
One is through the main menu: View | Panels
The other is to 'right click' on a toolbar. 
The check box for OSM Place Search is available using the second method, but not the first.

NB: This is also the case for at least one other panel I can see (undo/redo).

Comment: See also https://github.com/xcaeag/Nominatim-Qgis-Plugin/issues/1